# How to type argmin over a variable in plain TeX

Tags: math-mode, plain-tex

I am forced to use plain TeX instead of LaTeX and I don't know what is the proper way to type argmin  with some variable under it.

I know

```
$$ \min_b. $$
```

And I would like to do someething similar, but with argmin instead of min.

Sadly

```
$$ \argmin $$
```

doesn't exist :(

Please, does anyone have the knowladge how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Erhan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define it just like `\min` is defined:

```
\def\argmin{\mathop{\rm argmin}}
```